# Организация автоматического обновления информации с сервера

Tags: многопоточность, сервер, оптимизация-запросов

Python socket, tcp

Суть такова: Есть сервер, на него в рандомный момент приходит информация для разных пользователей.
Так же есть пользователь, которому эту информацию надо получить.
По сути мессенджер (хотя пишу не его)

Какие варианты я вижу варианты:

1. все активные клиенты на постоянной основе подключены к серверу и готовы принимать информацию. Но тогда, при большом количестве пользователей, на сервер будет идти высокая нагрузка на поддержание соединений
2. клиенты периодически подключаются, запрашивают у сервера наличие новой информации, получают её (если есть) и сразу отключаются. Можно обрабатывать сразу несколько пользователей потоками, если процессор будет простаивать в ожидании. В таком случае не уходят большие ресурсы на поддержание подключений, но появляются задержки и сложнее сделать пользователям приоритеты

Подскажите пожалуйста какой вариант лучше или предложите свой?) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В асинхронном режиме держать 100 000 соединений не проблема. Первый вариант подходит для небольших компаний.

Второй вариант не очень потом как в момент соединения надо Коннект авторизовать. Да и нагрузка неравномерна.

Между первым и вторым есть способ под названием поллинг. Коннект делается ненадолгое время (поддерживать не нужно), но при этом ловит события (мгновенная доставка) . также плюсом будет то что если на программе есть ограничение в количество соединений, то отвалившиеся освобождают слот и идут в конец очереди.

Заглючение : асинхронный сервер , ограничение количества коннектов чтоб влезли в память и полинг было бы отличной архитектурой. Но где же набрать столько коннектов чтоб уже не помещались в 512 мегабайт оперативки самого дешевого сервера?